# Linux script for probing ssh connection in a loop and start log command after connect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a host machine that gets rebooted or reconnected quite a few times. 
I want to have a script running on my dev machine that continuously tries to log into that machine and if successful runs a specific command (tailing the log data).
Edit: To clarify, the connection needs to stay open. The log command keeps tailing until I stop it manually.

What I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

IP=192.168.178.1

if (("$#" >= 1))
then
  IP=$1
fi

LOOP=1

trap 'echo "stopping"; LOOP=0' INT

while (( $LOOP==1 ))
do
if ping -c1 $IP
then
  echo "Host $IP reached" 
  sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -q user@$IP '<command would go here>'
else
  echo "Host $IP unreachable"
fi
sleep 1

done
```

The LOOP flag is not really used. The script is ended via CTRL-C.
Now this works if I do NOT add a command to be executed after the ssh and instead start the log output manually. On a disconnect the script keeps probing the connection and logs back in once the host is available again. 
Also when I disconnect from the host (CTRL-D) the script will log right back into the host if CTRL-C is not pressed fast enough.
When I add a command to be executed after ssh the loop is broken. So pressing (CTRL-C) does not only stop the log but also disconnects and ends the script on the dev machine.

I guess I have to spawn another shell somewhere or something like that?

1) I want the script to keep probing, log in and run a command completely automatically and fall back to probing when the connection breaks. 
2) I want to be able to stop the log on the host (CTRL-C) and thereby fall back to a logged in ssh connection to use it manually.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe best approach on "fixing" would be fixing requirements.

The problematic part is number "2)".
The problem is from how `SIGINT` works.

When triggered, it is sent to the current control group related to your terminal. Mostly this is the shell and any process started from there. With more modern shells (you seem to use `bash`), the shell manages control groups such that programs started *in the background* are disconnected (by having been assigned a different control group).

In your case the `ssh` is started in the foreground (from a script executed in the foreground), so it will receive the interrupt, forward it to the remote and terminate as soon as the remote end terminated. As by that time the script shell has processed its signal handler (specified by `trap`) it is going to exit the loop and terminate itself.

So, as you can see, you have overloaded `CTRL-C` to mean two things:

- terminate the monitoring script
- terminate the remote command and continue with whatever is specified for the remote side.

You might get closer to what you want if you drop the first effect (or at least make it more explicit). Then, calling a script on the remote side that does not terminate itself but just the tail command, will be step. In that case you will likely need to use `-t` switch on ssh to get a terminal allocated for allowing *normal* shell operation later.

This, will not allow for terminating the remote side with just `CTRL-C`. You always will need to *exit* the remote shell that is going to be run.

The essence of such a *remote script* might look like:

```
tail command
shell
```

of course you would need to add whatever parts will be necessary for your shell or coding style.

An alternate approach would be to keep the current remote command being terminated and add another `ssh` call for the case of being interrupted that is spanning the shell for interactive use. But in that case, also `CTRL-C will not be available for terminating the minoring altogether.

To achieve this you might try changing active interrupt handler with your monitoring script to trigger termination as soon as the remote side returns. However, this will cause a race condition between the user being able to recognize remote command terminated (and control has been returned to local script) and the proper interrupt handler being in place. You might be able to sufficiently lower that risk be first activating the new `trap` handler and then echoing the fact and maybe add a sleep to allow the user to react.

Comment: Your answer got me on the right path:
... ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -t user@$IP 'logtail; bash -l'
This is fine for me because "logtail" is a binary that runs on the host. CTRL-C stops that program and gets me back to the ssh login shell. Using "tail -f ..." instead, does not work and terminates the connection.

Comment: Also removing the "trap"  helps to clean up the exit behavior. CTRL-C stops the program on the host. CTRL-D disconnects. CTRL-C breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are saying.

Also, you should disable PasswordAuthentication in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and log by adding the public key of your home computer to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys

## ! /bin/sh

```
while [ true ];
do
    RESPONSE=`ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_host user@$IP 'tail /home/user/log.txt'`

    echo $RESPONSE

    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: "Not really sure what you are saying."
- What exactly do you not understand?

In this situation I cannot change ssh configs on that server. So sshpass is needed.

How does your script fulfill any of my requirements? I need an active connection that stays open to continuously monitor the log. 
If I just wanted to fetch it, I would simply use scp.

Comment: well, see if ` helps.  you want to keep the connection open?  I'll think about it

Comment: ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_host "user@$IP" 'tail -f /home/user/log.txt' in a loop should work